# Ambos tratamentos de erros são iguais?

Tags: php, laravel, característica-linguagem

Estou com uma grande duvida referente a um codigo visualizado referente a tratamento de erros, tenho 2 opções de tratamento de erros, uma está sendo bastante utilizada em um sistema que estou fazendo, e a outra é o `try` e `catch`. Ambos exemplos estão sendo feitos em PHP utilizando o *framework* **Laravel**.

Primeiro exemplo:

```
 $variavel = Model::where('id',$id)->first()->delete(); 
    if($variavel){
        alert()->success('Sucesso!', ' removido com sucesso');
        return back();
    }else{
        alert()->error('Erro!', 'Erro ao remover!');
        return back();
    }
```

Agora utilizando o *try* e o *catch*

```
try{
    Model::where('id',$id)->first()->delete(); 

    alert()->success('Sucesso!', ' removido com sucesso');
    return back();
}catch(Exception $e){
      alert()->error('Erro!', 'Erro ao remover!');
      return back();
}
```

Entre os dois exemplos, existe alguma diferença referente a tratamento de erros? Os dois são maneiras corretas para ser feito o tratamento de erros?

Answer (score -1):

Forma central de remover registro com Laravel:

```
public function destroy($id){

   $model = Model::findOrFail($id);

   $model->delete();

   alert()->success('Sucesso!', ' removido com sucesso');

   return redirect()->back();   

}
```

Comment: Lucas, eu uso essa forma, mas estou com a duvida sobre o tratamento de erros, por exemplo, citei dois exemplos ali em cima. Eu quero entender sobre essas duas formas que citei se em quesito "tratamento de erros" alguma delas divergem em alguma situação.

Comment: Passa o FindOrFail no try catch e usa o throw para tratar o erro

Comment: Se quiser eu faço dois exemplo um com throw e um com session que é a forma que eu uso